# useState function is not working in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I want to change a state (`filterConsultantId`) with a useState function (`setFilterConsultantId`) after I trigger a normal function (`handleConsultantChange`) and I expect the state value is changed when I use the state in another normal function (`getActiveLeads`). But the state didn't change. Please see my React functional component below:

```
const TabActiveLeads = ({
    ...
}) => {
    const [filterConsultantId, setFilterConsultantId] = useState('');   
    
    //after this arrow function triggered, 
    const handleConsultantChange = (event) => {
        setFilterConsultantId(event.target.value); //and the filterConsultantId should be changed here
        
        //this getActiveLeads function is called
        getActiveLeads();
    };
    
    const getActiveLeads = () => {
        
        // but the filterConsultantId here is not changed after it should be changed inside handleConsultantChange function
        console.log(filterConsultantId);
    }; 
};

export default TabActiveLeads;
```

I don't understand, why `filterConsultantId` is not changed inside the `getActiveLeads` function? Previously it should be changed by calling `setFilterConsultantId` inside the `handleConsultantChange` function.

Thanks for any help..

Comment: does this help you in this issue: https://ysfaran.github.io/blog/post/0002-use-state-with-promise/

Comment: @SinanYaman it's too complicated but thanks for the link. it is a nice reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setFilterConsultantId` is the asynchronous method, so you can't get the updated value of `filterConsultantId` right after `setFilterConsultantId`.
You should get it inside `useEffect` with adding a dependency `filterConsultantId`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(filterConsultantId);
}, [filterConsultantId]);
```

Comment: thanks! as a newbie, I was still confused with your answer but after I try, may I add: this useEffect should be placed inside the react functional component. Outside any normal function.

Comment: yes, that' right. for more details, refer to the doc. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html