# How can I access my react hooks state from inside a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have an app that shows some questions when the user presses a button. On each questions I have a condition to determine if the "Back" button should be shown on the question - `appState.questions.length > 0`.

My problem is that the state is not being reached from the function where I am calling it.

```
let questionComponent = (currentCardKey, textAreaText = "") => {
    console.log(`Question length inside: ${appState.questions.length}`)
    return <Question
        textAreaText={"ereer"}
        // I can not access appState from here.
        shouldShowBackButton={appState.questions.length > 0}
        measureTextChangeHandler={measureTextChangeHandler}
        onChosenDataTypeChanged={onChosenDataTypeChanged}
        aimTextChangeHandler={aimTextChangeHandler}
        onButtonClicked={onButtonClicked}
        currentCardKey={currentCardKey}/>
}
```

The structure of my code.

```
function App(){
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState(
        {
            questions: [], //[<Question />, <Question />]
            independentVariablesCount: 0,
        }
    )
    const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState();
    
    const addToQuestion = (questionObject) => {
        setAppState(prevState => {
            questionLength.current = appState.questions.length
            return {...prevState, questions: [...prevState.questions, questionObject]}
        })
    }

    // I can access appState outside the function
    
    let questionComponent = (currentCardKey, textAreaText = "") => {

        console.log(`Question length inside: ${appState.questions.length}`)

        return <Question
            textAreaText={"ereer"}
           // I can not access appState inside this function
            shouldShowBackButton={appState.questions.length > 0}
            measureTextChangeHandler={measureTextChangeHandler}
            onChosenDataTypeChanged={onChosenDataTypeChanged}
            aimTextChangeHandler={aimTextChangeHandler}
            onButtonClicked={onButtonClicked}
            currentCardKey={currentCardKey}/>
    }

    const onButtonClicked = (_buttonText, previousCardComponent) => {
        const previousCard = previousCardComponent
        const previousCardMainText = previousCardComponent.props.mainText
        ...
        switch (_buttonText) {
            case buttonText["NEXT"]:
                switch (previousCardMainText){
                    case questionData["CAT_QUESTION"]:
                        addToQuestion(previousCard)
                        setCurrentCard(questionComponent("CAT_FOOD_QUESTION"))
                        break
                }
            ...
                break
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>{currentCard}</div>
    )
}
```

I have tried updating the function inside `useEffect()` but that does not solve the problem. I have searched for solutions such as [useState function is not working in functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247567/usestate-function-is-not-working-in-functional-component) and [React hooks setState not updating immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510211/react-hooks-setstate-not-updating-immediately) but none of these work.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Hi, I have access to the state inside and outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I did wrong, I did not remember to add the first question to the state array when the start button is clicked and I did not make a way for the question component to be re-rendered with the correct value when the question length changes. Used the `useRef` hook to store the `questionComponent` function.

So I used the `useRef` hook to store the `questionComponent` and used the `addToQuestion` function I had.

```
const questionComponent = useRef()

useEffect(()=>{
    questionComponent.current = (currentCardKey, textAreaText = "") => {
        console.log(`Question length inside: ${appState.questions.length}`)
        return <Question
            textAreaText={"ereer"}
            shouldShowBackButton={appState.questions.length > 0}
            measureTextChangeHandler={measureTextChangeHandler}
            onChosenDataTypeChanged={onChosenDataTypeChanged}
            aimTextChangeHandler={aimTextChangeHandler}
            onButtonClicked={onButtonClicked}
            currentCardKey={currentCardKey}/>
    }
})

const onStartButtonClick = () => {
    setStartButtonIsClicked(true)
    setCurrentCard(questionComponent.current("CAT_FOOD_QUESTION"))
    addToQuestion(questionComponent.current("CAT_FOOD_QUESTION"))
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you access to the initial appState due to the javascript clousure feature, so the appState length keeps 0 all the time.

try this:

```js
let questionComponent = React.useMemo((...) => {}, [appState]);
```

then you can access to the newest appState

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. `questionComponent` is not recognised as a function.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use useCallback?

```
Const questionComponent = useCallback((currentCardKey, textAreaText = "") => {

        console.log(`Question length inside: ${appState.questions.length}`)

        return <Question
            textAreaText={"ereer"}
           // I can not access appState inside this function
            shouldShowBackButton={appState.questions.length > 0}
            measureTextChangeHandler={measureTextChangeHandler}
            onChosenDataTypeChanged={onChosenDataTypeChanged}
            aimTextChangeHandler={aimTextChangeHandler}
            onButtonClicked={onButtonClicked}
            currentCardKey={currentCardKey}/>
    },[appState])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but this does not work.